# Sorting array coming from computed property, in a method also sorts the original array (that comes from the computed property)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, computed-properties

Im building a vue application for quizzes, I want to display the all the previous results of the person that has taken the quiz. For that I fetch the results from my backend and then pass them to the "view" component with a computed property:

```
   computed: {
    allResults() {
      return this.$store.state.allResults;
    },
```

I want to also sort out the best results, and the most recent results and display them separately, In order to do that I have the following methods:

```
 bestResults() {
    let orderedArray = this.allResults;

    orderedArray.sort((a, b) =>
      a.score < b.score ? 1 : a.score > b.score ? -1 : 0
    );
    let half = Math.round(orderedArray.length / 2);

    let bestResults = orderedArray.slice(0, half);
    return bestResults;
  },

 recentResults() {
    let recentResults = this.allResults.slice(0, 5);
    return recentResults;
  }
```

This works, however it sorts the `allResults` array in a way that shows the scores from highest to lowest, which is what I do in the `bestResults()` function. This is a problem since I want to display the `recentResults` based on date, which should show the most recent result on top.

Comment: how do you know the recent sores?

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz. They are the ones that are recorded last, so originally they are last in the array, I'm planning to reverse the array with reverse() and therefore get the last recorded items to be on top and display it that way.

Comment: Hi @Rohit Jindal, I will display the best results separately, than the recent results. There will be two components, one showing the best results of all time, and one showing the 5 most recent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you first sort the array in `bestResults()`, then use the sorted array in `recentResults`.

As a solution, you can create a new array with the same elements and sort that, which will leave the original array untouched:

```js
 bestResults() {
    let orderedArray = [...this.allResults];

    orderedArray.sort((a, b) =>
      a.score < b.score ? 1 : a.score > b.score ? -1 : 0
    );
    let half = Math.round(orderedArray.length / 2);

    let bestResults = orderedArray.slice(0, half);
    return bestResults;
  },

 recentResults() {
    let recentResults = this.allResults.slice(0, 5);
    return recentResults;
  }
```